# How to configure NLog 3.0 in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, nlog

NLog have just been released their new version 3.0 but I can't right configure my VS2008 to work with ...

With version 1.0 you have an exe in order to install NLog's dll and component for VS2008 (right click>add reference>NLog Config file).New version only have NLog.dll and NLog.xml file.

In this page (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Visual-Studio-support), they said that :

- Intellisense is already integrated : "All you need to do is add two namespace declarations ..." => OK
- Integration with Add/Reference dialog : "NLog Setup registers the appropriate AssemblyFolders entry in registry so that Visual Studio is able to locate the *.dll files" => KO because there is no setup, only dll
- New Item Templates : "NLog comes with 3 sample configuration files that can be quickly added to you project through Add New Item dialog" => KO, nothing add to right click

Do you know how to configure NLog 3.0 for Visual Studio 2008 ?

NB : For VS2012 and above, Nlog is integrated with NuGet, everything works fine :-)

Thanks for your help

Cooxkie

Comment: One way to tackle this problem could be: make NuGet available for VS2008. See [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetSupportForVisualStudio2008.aspx) from Scott Hanselman how to do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed by myself to configure NLog 3.0 in VS2008, doing it mannualy ;-)
Just adding NLog references and create my own NLog.config file.

Discussion in NLog Forum :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nlog-users/YdsYzSLTNjU